# Fancytree complains Ajax request returned a string using Cherrypy

Tags: ajax, json, cherrypy, fancytree

Hi I am very new to use cherrypy as backend with fanytree as front end.

here is my fanytree side of the code:

```
source: {
   url : '/test_data'
},
```

on the cherrypy side, I implemented function called test_data

```
@cherrypy.expose
@cherrypy.tools.json_out()
def test_data(self, **kwargs):
  cherrypy.response.headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
  return '[ {"title":"abc", "folder": true, "key": "1", "children":[ {"title":"b","key":"2"}] }]'
```

So I see the request comes to cherrypy as

```
'GET /test_data?_=some number...
```

On browser I see my return object back but it failed on check:

```
if (typeof data === "string") {
      $.error("Ajax request returned a string (did you get the JSON dataType wrong?).");
 }
```

I read somewhere that you need content-type to be json but I already have. What am I missing?

Comment: Check what the server returns including content type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CherryPy JSON output tool, `cherrypy.tools.json_out`, takes care of MIME and turning your data into a JSON string. So if you use it the method should look like:

```
@cherrypy.expose
@cherrypy.tools.json_out()
def test_data(self, **kwargs):
  return [{
    "title"    : "abc", 
    "folder"   : True, 
    "key"      : 1, 
    "children" : [{"title": "b", "key": 2}] 
  }]
```

Otherwise if you want to do it yourself it'll be:

```
import json

@cherrypy.expose
def test_data(self, **kwargs):
  cherrypy.response.headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
  return json.dumps([{
    "title"    : "abc", 
    "folder"   : True, 
    "key"      : 1, 
    "children" : [{"title": "b", "key": 2}] 
  }])
```

Then make sure you've restarted CherryPy app, and look in web developer tools or FireBug network tab to verify response headers and content.

Comment: This is exactly the information I needed. The story is if I specify @cherrypy.tools.json_out(), I will have to return a python list, can not use `'` around the return since it will treat as string. Of course @mar10 also corrected point out that it would be better to construct in dicts to avoid such issue.

Answer (score 1):

The content type is ok, but the string you are returning is not valid json (for example the keys must be enclosed in double quotes).
I would recommend to prepare your data as list of dicts and then use 'json.dumps()' to convert to JSON.
(Maybe the json_out tool does the same but I would guess that even then you should return a list of dicts instead of a string.)

Comment: Ok, I changed as you suggested, fancytree still has the same complaints.

Comment: The string that you return in your sample is definitely invalid JSON (not even valid Python, btw.)

Comment: Ok, I edited the original post to reflect this suggestion. But fancytree still think it is string type not json object.